# Python List accepting None and specifific type but not Any

Tags: python, types, typing

Sorry as maybe its a bit silly question. Normally, I code in strong-typing languages like Java or Typescript, recently I need to be closer to Python and I have a problem with typing.

In my python application (3.8.2) I have an array of objects of 'Vehicle' type.
I would like to add 'None' type. However, I am not able to do that as the compiler gives me a message:

`Expected type 'Vehicle' (matched generic type '_T'), got 'None' instead`

code:

```
  self.lane_segments: List[Vehicle] = []
  for i in range(element_numbers):
     self.lane_segments.append(None)
```

is there any possibility to define a type which will also accept None?

Comment: It should be something like `List[Union[Vehicle, NoneType]]` or equivalent

Comment: Or the shorthand `List[Optional[Vehicle]]`.

Comment: Thanks, guys! Both of this solution works. Appreciate such fast response :)